# Space with grep?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a csv file like this :

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

I would like to analyze an other csv file with the csv file with the days of the week. My script will take Monday, analyze the file and extract all the lines that contain the word Monday, then switch to Tuesday etc....

I use this command to do this :

```
grep -wf daysfile.csv myothercsv.csv > file.csv
```

This command works pretty well, but the result is :

```
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
```

But I would like to have spaces like this :

```
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX

Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk`

```
grep -wf daysfile.csv myothercsv.csv |awk -F: '{if(f!=$1)print ""; f=$1; print $0;}'

Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX
Monday XXXX XXX XXX

Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Tuesday XXXX XXXX XXXX

Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
Wednesday XXXX XXXX XXXX
```

Comment: IMHO, I am not sure if OP has mentioned that `:` is field separator, may be you are trying to do which I did on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069502/5866580

Comment: Your command worke very well ! But it only adds one space between each group of days. Can you tell me how to put 2 spaces between them ?

Comment: Change `print ""` with `print "\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output of grep to

```
perl -ape 'print "\n" if $previous and $previous ne $F[0]; $previous = $F[0]'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `-a` splits each input line into the @F array

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` could you please try following.

```
your_grep_command | awk 'prev!=$1 && prev{print ""} {prev=$1;print}'
```

---

---

Since OP has NOT provided samples so couldn't test it, could you please try to run directly this command? In spite of passing `grep` output to another command once and let us know then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} prev!=$1{print ""} ($0 in a);{prev=$1}'  daysfile.csv <(sort -k1 myothercsv.csv)
```

Comment: @Ezzmazz, could you please check this solution once and let me now if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `grep -wf daysfile.csv myothercsv.csv` is working for you as you described.  The data in `myothercsv.csv` must already be sorted by days of the week, since the grep command would simply print any line that has any matching word in the `daysfile.csv` as they are ordered.

If you want to search for each word in the `daysfile.csv` sequentially, then you probably want following:

```
cat daysfile.csv | while read line; do grep "$line" myothercsv.csv; done
```

Then you can apply the other answers here that refer to adding blank lines (when a different first word is detected) to the output.

Also, a different way to do this is to insert a blank line into myothercsv file, and insert `^$` lines to your daysfile.  Here's an example, notice the first line in myothercsv file is a blank.

```
$ cat daysfile.csv
mon
^$
tue
^$
wed
^$

$ cat myothercsv.csv

mon,1
tue,2
wed,3
mon,4
tue,5
wed,6

$ cat daysfile.csv | while read line; do grep "$line" myothercsv.csv; done
mon,1
mon,4

tue,2
tue,5

wed,3
wed,6
```